# Не получается отправить письмо из-за приводимости типов

Tags: c#, unity3d, smtp

Делаю приложение на Unity (C#), которое должно давать возможность пользователю отсылать заявки для конкурса. Решил реализовать это посредством отправки писем через smtp-сервер. Но в процессе разработки столкнулся с проблемой невозможности неявного преобразования NetworkCredential в ICredentialsByHost. Вроде бы нужно просто явно преобразовать одно в другое - но это решение, при отправке письма, генерирует исключение "InvalidOperationException: SSL authentication error: RemoteCertificateNotAvailable, RemoteCertificateChainErrors".
Я пробовал скопировать этот код в новый проект - и, о чудо, там всё работает, так, как написано во всех гайдах
[Скриншот](https://yadi.sk/i/_3uXJgPU3Z8X3h)

Comment: Пробовали [самостоятельно](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=SSL+authentication+error%3A+RemoteCertificateNotAvailable%2C+RemoteCertificateChainErrors&rlz=1C1GCEA_enGB759GB760&oq=SSL+authentication+error%3A+RemoteCertificateNotAvailable%2C+RemoteCertificateChainErrors&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) искать [ответы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148019/authentication-or-decryption-has-failed-when-sending-mail-to-gmail-using-ssl)?

Comment: @tym32167, мне больше интересно узнать, почему один и тот же фрагмент кода может давать разный результат